# Checking the Hasse-Weil bound for genus zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, function-fields

According to Stichtenoth's *Algebraic Function Fields and Codes*, the Hasse-Weil bound theorem is:

> The number $N$ of places of $F/\mathbb{F}_q$ of degree one satisfies $|N-(q+1)|\leq 2gq^{1/2}$.
>
> [here $q\in\mathbb{N}$ is a prime and $g$ is the genus of $F/\mathbb{F}_q$]

I've tried to check the theorem for some case when $g=0$, where we should have $N=q+1$. I took $y^2=x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$, whose rational solutions are exactly $(0,1),(0,2)$, so $N=2\neq 4=q+1$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing points are in fact at infinity !
The curve you cosider is the restriction of the projective curve $$y^2=x^2+z^2$$ to the affine plane $z=1$. Be careful that the theorem applies to projective curves !

Hence the points $(1:1:0)$ and $(1:-1:0)$ are the missing ones !

Comment: Oh, yes, you're totally right! But how do the points $(1:1:0),(1:-1:0)$ translate into subrings $\mathbb{F}_q\subset R\subset F$?

Comment: I ask this because Stichtenoth always talks about places in algebraic language

Comment: I don't know the notations of your book. Algebraically, a point corresponds to a morphism of schemes $Spec(\mathbb{F}_q) \rightarrow C$ where $C$ denotes the curve. Is that what you want me to explain ?

Comment: I'm still not familiar with the language of schemes. The author defines a place as a principal ideal $P$ of some valuation ring $K\subsetneq\mathcal{O}\subsetneq F$. I don't know what are the corresponding $P\subset \mathcal{O}$ for the points $(1:1:0), (1:-1:0)$

Comment: I think you mean prime ideal and that the ring $\mathcal{O}$ is not necessarily of valuation (you can have a valuation ring by localizing at the prime ideal). The ring $\mathcal{O}$ corrseponding to those points is the ring of coordinates in the chart $x=1$. If you know how coordinates in a projective space work, it is an easy (and good) exercize to see it is $$\mathbb{F}_3[X^{-1},YX^{-1}]/(X^{-2}+(YX^{-1})^2-1).$$ then the places are given by the ideals $(X^{-1}(YX^{-1}\pm 1))$.